# How to rearrange for a variable with SymPy

Tags: python, math, sympy, symbolic-math, equation-solving

I have a complex equation that I would like to rearrange for a variable `vz(t) = ...`.
[image]

What is the most elegant way in SymPy ? I have determined the upper equation as a solution of an ODE:

```
import sympy as sym
sym.init_printing()
t,m,k,g,v0,psi = sym.symbols("t,m,k,g,v_0,psi")

vz = sym.Function('v_z')


eqn = sym.Eq(-k*vz(t)**2 - m*vz(t).diff(t) - m*g,0)

sol = sym.dsolve(eqn, ics = {vz(0): v0*sym.sin(psi)})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you show can be simplified into solving involving `atan` and then rearranged. Some assumptions are needed on the symbols to make that rearrangement possible though. Actually if you set all symbols to be positive then you'll get a simpler result from `dsolve` in the first place:

```
In [51]: import sympy as sym
    ...: sym.init_printing()
    ...: t,m,k,g,v0,psi = sym.symbols("t,m,k,g,v_0,psi", positive=True)
    ...: 
    ...: vz = sym.Function('v_z', positive=True)
    ...: 
    ...: 
    ...: eqn = sym.Eq(-k*vz(t)**2 - m*vz(t).diff(t) - m*g,0)
    ...: 
    ...: sol = sym.dsolve(eqn, ics = {vz(0): v0*sym.sin(psi)})


In [52]: 

In [52]: sol
Out[52]: 
                  ⎛      ⎛           ⎛√k⋅v₀⋅sin(ψ)⎞⎞⎞
                  ⎜      ⎜       atan⎜────────────⎟⎟⎟
                  ⎜      ⎜  t        ⎝   √g⋅√m    ⎠⎟⎟
         √g⋅√m⋅tan⎜√g⋅√k⋅⎜- ── + ──────────────────⎟⎟
                  ⎝      ⎝  √m         √g⋅√k       ⎠⎠
v_z(t) = ────────────────────────────────────────────
                              √k
```

Introducing a parameter `α = sqrt(m*g/k)` this becomes:

```
In [65]: sol.subs(sqrt(k), sqrt(m)*sqrt(g)/alpha).expand()
Out[65]: 
              ⎛    ⎛v₀⋅sin(ψ)⎞   g⋅t⎞
v_z(t) = α⋅tan⎜atan⎜─────────⎟ - ───⎟
              ⎝    ⎝    α    ⎠    α ⎠
```